# Whats the Tallest Unicode glyph?

Tags: glyphs, unicode

Whats the tallest Unicode glyph (By the characters look). The tallest I've seen them is like the giant half parenthesis, that stretch 3 lines.

---

Like this one: ⎝ (This font it only goes 2 lines). I'm trying to pull off a "visual glitch" with a different project. Also for bonus if someone can find me the WIDEST Glyph, id appreciate it.

Comment: What a wonderfully weird question to have

Comment: Aside from swashes, generally speaking the italics lower-case f spans the descender, ascender, and x-height. An Em dash comes in denominations, 2-em, 3-em.

Comment: interesting, Ill have to check it out. Im only searching for this character to use it as a sort of "exploit" in a game that has to do with custom names.

Comment: V̶̢̜̲͓͍͍̼̼̈́̿̃̍̄i̴̡̢̜̝̜̯̠̺̦̅͐̈́͌̇̉̉s̵̭̳̜̲̦̜͎̪͔̭̑̈́ű̸̦a̶̬̰͓̜͍̠̩̐͂̾͗̈͐̐̇̈́͜͝l̶̢͓͔̈̑̀̏̒̕͝ ̸̨̱̪̣̠͔̱̖̬͇́̇̑̏́̏̕͝͠g̴̪̫̤̬̎̔ḻ̸̪̺͖̜̺̣̖̺͒į̴̧͙̦̫̀̈́͌̆͜ṭ̶̨͍̲̰̮̭̘̤͎̽͐͋̈̎͠c̴̛̣̰̒͗̑́̑͐͛̚͝h̵̨̡̛͇̗̏̈̈́͂͐̋̚͝?̵̧̪̳͌̇̍̚͜ ̷̨͈̰̱͖̣̗͚̲̻̉̈̌̋̈́̋̎͝Ŵ̸̨̘͉̘͓̻͚̲̥̎͂̄͌̍͋̚ḧ̴̜͖̳͗͛̃̍̉͗͘̕ą̷̛͙̙̝̯͎̼̖͂̍t̷̥̫͇̝̯͙́͂̏̈́͂̃͊̃̉͆͜ͅͅ ̶̜̗̮̤͋̄̊v̸̳͙̙̭̓̽̋͛͜͠i̸̢͕̱̦̞̞͎̖̤̻̒̀̅̎͘͝͝͝s̸̲̞̳̻̄͒̂͑͊̃̚ù̷̡̼͙̈́̑̉͘a̶̢̼̣̫̰͉̬̱̩͊̇́̀͆͛͐͛́̚l̴͍̺̼̞̰̣̯͔̲̏̈́̀̈͊̒̽͋̓͝ ̶̢̛͓̗͕͂̔ģ̶̰̗͔̟̘͕͚̙͌͑l̵̮͍͚̰̳̀i̵͔͈̤͖͚̪͖͔̙̗̽ṯ̴̜͕̗̙́͛ć̷̢͕͓̦̙̦͈̲̠̉̆͊͐͑̔́h̴̭̩̼̃̌̾͐?̵͙̣̠̝͔̬͗̃̈́͌

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on the font.

Take the font Zapfino, for instance. It has multiple glyphs for the same unicode characters, some of which are very curly and tall.

[image]

Comment: cool! although how are we suppose to use the characters as it is an image?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. You have the name of the font.

Comment: The illustration @KrisVanBael supplied is an image because Stack doesn't support using any random font in answers. As has been mentioned, you have the name of the font; try it on actual text.